# Prove that $x^2-5y=3$ has no integer solutions.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

Here is my attempt:

$x^2-5y=3$ is the same as $2x^2-10y=6$, which is equivalent to $2x^2=10y+6$. 
This means that 2 divides $x^2$. Since 2 is prime, then 2 divides x, or $x=2k$ for some integer $k$.

Then we have that $(2k)^2-5y=3$, or $4k^2=5y+3$. This implies that 2 divides $5y+3$, but this is a contradiction.

This looks valid to me but any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I do not see how you can say that 2 divides $x^2$?

Comment: You're right, I guess saying 2 divides 2x^2 is different than saying 2 divides x^2

Comment: Yeah, that is correct.

Comment: I would try looking at this equation mod 5

Comment: You write "This implies that $2$ divides $5+3$, but this is a contradiction."  Why?  What if $y = 1$ or indeed any odd number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**  $x^2 - 5y = 3 \iff x^2 = 5y + 3$.  Now observe that the units digit of a perfect square must be one of the following digits:  $0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 9$.

Answer (score 3):

If $x^2-5y=3$ then  $x^2\equiv3\pmod 5,$

but that would contradict that, 
for all integers $x$, $x^2\equiv0, 1, $ or $4\pmod5$.